# Equation of curve normal to a family of ellipses

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, curves

*I have tried to describe this problem as best as I can but I realize that (because I am not a trained mathematician) my description may fall short. Therefore I am prepared to edit this question until it is clear and unambiguous.*

---

Consider an ellipse $A$

$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1
$$

which is fully embedded in a circle $E$

$$
x^2 + y^2 = R^2
$$

Such that there exists a family of ellipses

$$
\frac{x^2}{(sa + (1 - s)R)^2} + \frac{y^2}{(sb + (1 - s)R)^2} = 1
$$

parametrized by $0 \le s \le 1$.

I'd like to determine the equation of the curve (starting) from an arbitrary point $P(x,y)$ on $A$ to $E$ such that the curve is normal to the family of ellipses, as shown in the figure below.

[image: Family of ellipses embedded by a circle and an ellipse]

All I know is that this problem has some characteristics of an initial value ODE.

Comment: With a little bit of luck, that's a hyperbola, or maybe some other conic. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Arthur you are right. It the intersecting curve is a [hyperbola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confocal_conic_sections).